# Linux: 'ls' all jpg files recursively in csv

Tags: linux, csv, find, ls

I'm trying to find a way to list all jpg images in all subdirectories and in csv format without the dir name present.

```
ls -R -1 -m . | grep '.jpg'
```

The ls command does output to csv fine, but the grep command breaks the csv format making each file appear on a new line instead of comma seperated.

I know I can use 'find' to list images but it seems to output the files in a different order than 'ls' and I don't see a output to csv parameter for 'find'

I need the images in each subdirectory on 1 comma seperated line.

Comment: What if you run into a file with a comma in the filename!

Comment: please edit your Q to show what  your `.csv` should contain for the `ls -l -m` output. Also, you should include your best attempt to create a .csv file on your own. Do you know about `printf` from the cmd-line or inside of `awk` or other languages? Good luck.

Comment: `*.jpg` is an incorrect regular expression for `grep`. `*` has to follow another character, it means any number of the previous character.

Comment: You should write a simple script that reads its standard input, and converts it to CSV format. Then pipe the output of `ls -R | grep '\.jpg'` to that script.

Comment: Barmar, you're right. I was using ".jpg" actually. Will edit the Q

Comment: Barmar, won't that put all the files in one comma seperated line ? instead of each dir's contents on one line ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of what you expect the output to be? In the question, you say that you expect it to be "1 comma separated line", but in the comments you say you want each directory to be a different line.

Comment: `ls` is not an appropriate tool for programmatic use. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Re: `find`, you can actually control its output format. With the GNU version, `find . -name '*jpg' -printf '%f\n' | sort | tr '\n' ','` will emit names in sorted form with a comma after each, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want.  Each outputted line is a list of jpgs in a single directory separated by commas.

```
ls -d */ | xargs -i{} sh -c 'cd {};ls -m *jpg'
```

If you wanted to know which line was which directory you could run it in 2 steps like this

```
ls -d */ > dirs.txt 
cat dirs.txt | xargs -i{} sh -c 'cd {};ls -m *txt'
```

and then the first line in `dirs.txt` would correspond to each line of output.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to shell injection attacks. If this is being run in a directory structure other users can upload to, you really wouldn't want there to be a directory created with `mkdir -p $'./hello/$(rm -rf ~)/'` with at least one `*.jpg` file inside it.

Comment: Consider instead the safer (and more efficient, since it reuses one shell for multiple directories) alternative `find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for dir; do cd "$dir" && ls -m *jpg; done' _ {} +`.